# How to GROUP and SUM a pivot table column in Eloquent relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationships

In Laravel 4; I have model `Project` and `Part`, they have a many-to-many relationship with a pivot table `project_part`. The pivot table has a column `count` which contains the number of a part ID used on a project, e.g.:

```
id  project_id  part_id count
24  6           230     3
```

Here the `project_id` 6, is using 3 pieces of `part_id` 230.

One part may be listed multiple times for the same project, e.g.:

```
id  project_id  part_id count
24  6           230     3
92  6           230     1
```

When I show a parts list for my project I do not want to show `part_id` twice, so i group the results.

My **Projects** model has this:

```
public function parts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Part', 'project_part', 'project_id', 'part_id')
         ->withPivot('count')
         ->withTimestamps()
         ->groupBy('pivot_part_id')
}
```

But of course my `count` value is not correct, and here comes my problem: **How do I get the sum of all grouped parts for a project?**

Meaning that my parts list for `project_id` 6 should look like:

```
part_id count
230     4
```

I would really like to have it in the `Projects`-`Parts` relationship so I can eager load it.

I can not wrap my head around how to do this without getting the N+1 problem, any insight is appreciated.

---

**Update:** As a temporary work-around I have created a presenter method to get the total part count in a project. But this is giving me the N+1 issue.

```
public function sumPart($project_id)
{
    $parts = DB::table('project_part')
        ->where('project_id', $project_id)
        ->where('part_id', $this->id)
        ->sum('count');

    return $parts;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [code source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L298):

> We need to alias all of the pivot columns with the "pivot_" prefix so we can easily extract them out of the models and put them into the pivot relationships when they are retrieved and hydrated into the models.

So you can do the same with `select` method

```
public function parts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Part', 'project_part', 'project_id', 'part_id')
        ->selectRaw('parts.*, sum(project_part.count) as pivot_count')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->groupBy('project_part.pivot_part_id')
}
```

Comment: That seems to work, only I had to add `parts.*` to the `selectRaw` as well, otherwise I didn't get any of the other fields. I'll test it thoroughly and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think you need to add `parts.*`, Eloquent [add it](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L283) behind the scenes.

Comment: That's what I though as well, but it's not part of the query without adding it.

Comment: pretty weird, how you actually build your query?  can you share executed queries? what version you use? what exactly  you get without `part.*` (dump it please)?

Comment: I am using Laravel 4.2, I have moved things around a bit. I do the `selectRaw` in the controller, not on the relationship, this way I can choose whether I want to merge rows or not. http://pastebin.com/KTZRFigU Does this cover it?

Comment: I meant exactly what version 4.2.(?) ... anyway, I tested with an old version 4.2.1 and it works perfectly, but for L4.2.16 it seems that you must add `parts.*` which is more logical (answer updated). As note, when you use a join ( this is the case with belongsToMany) it is preferable to add the name of table to your columns `orderBy('tableName.description_en')`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I do use version 4.2.16. Thank you for the tip, and the solution. Much appreciated :)

Comment: cool, this is clean solution for pivotting sum of group, at least for my case :)

Answer (score 32):

Try to sum in `Collection`,

```php
$project->parts->sum('pivot.count');
```

This is best way I found. It's clean (easy to read) and able to re-use all of your scope, ordering and relation attribute caching in `parts` many-to-many defination.

@hebron No N+1 problem for this solution if you use `with('parts')` to [eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Because `$project->parts` (**without** funtion call) is a cached attribute, return a instance of [Collection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections) with all your data. And `sum('pivot.count')` is a method of `Collection` which contains pure funcional helpers (not relative to database, like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) in js world).

Full example:

Definition of relation parts:

```php
class Project extends Model
{
    public function parts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Part', 'project_part', 'project_id', 'part_id')
            ->withPivot('count')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

When you use it (note that eager load is important to avoid N+1 problem),

```php
App\Project::with('parts')->get()->each(function ($project) {
    dump($project->parts->sum('pivot.count'));
});
```

Or you can define the sum function in Project.php,

```php
class Project extends Model
{
    ...

    /**
     * Get parts count.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function partsCount()
    {
        return $this->parts->sum('pivot.count');
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid `with('parts')` on caller side (eager load parts by default), you can add a `$with` attribute

```php
class Project extends Model
{
    /**
     * The relations to eager load on every query.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['parts'];

    ...
}
```

Comment: Won't this give me the N+1 problem?

Comment: @hebron No N+1 problem of this solution. Example have been updated.

Answer (score 2):

The best way that you can use is:

```
$project->parts->sum('pivot.count');
```

I faced the same problem, but this solved my issue.