# Laravel - Eloquent relationship belongsToMany groupBy "Syntax error or access violation" Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

From this question: [How to GROUP and SUM a pivot table column in Eloquent relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267550/how-to-group-and-sum-a-pivot-table-column-in-eloquent-relationship)

I used this code in my `User` Model:

```
public function teams() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Team', 'team_members', 'user_id', 'team_id')
        ->groupBy('pivot_team_id');
}
```

I wanted to use `->groupBy()` because in my `team`s, a single `user` can act as multiple `team_member`s for different roles. I do not want `team` records duplicate.

**But when I try to access e.g. with this code on my page `dd(Auth::user()->teams)`, Laravel threw the following exception:**

> `` SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'laravel.teams.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `teams`.*, `team_members`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `team_members`.`team_id` as `pivot_team_id` from `teams` inner join `team_members` on `teams`.`id` = `team_members`.`team_id` where `team_members`.`user_id` = 3 group by `pivot_team_id`) ``

Then I tried running that exact same SQL in the error by myself, it worked:
[image: Working example]

**Why is that so? And where did I get it wrong?**

Comment: See if this helps - https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager/issues/144

Comment: @ayip It does work now, but it seems like a hack. There must be a way to do it without disabling full group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help of @ayip, the problem was with the `strict` mode in `config/database.php`.

There are only 2 solutions so far:

1. Disable strict mode; or
2. Include all columns selected in the `belongsToMany` tables in `groupBy` or in aggregate functions such as `SUM()` etc.

This is an example in 2:

```
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Team', 'team_members', 'user_id', 'team_id')
        ->selectRaw('sum(team_members.team_member_role_id) as pivot_count') //because this is different across records beside others in group by
        ->groupBy('teams.id', 'teams.name', 'teams.description', 'team_members.user_id', 'team_members.team_id');
```

Please notice that you can choose to `SUM()` columns in records that are different but can be grouped by the rest of the columns and you don't care about that specific column. For example:

```
job         |   gender
programmer  |   M
programmer  |   F
accountant  |   M
```

If you don't want to distinguish between jobs with different genders, then `SUM()` the `gender`, so you don't have to add that column after `GROUP BY`.