# How can I implement SUM() in Laravel relations?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, relationship

Here is my query which works as well:

```
SELECT sum(r.rating) as rank,b.* FROM books as b
LEFT JOIN ranks as r ON b.id = r.book_id
WHERE 1
GROUP BY (b.id)
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Now I want to do the same in Laravel. Here is what I've tried:

```
// Book model
class Book extends Model
{
    public function ranks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Rank::class)->sum("rating");
    }
}

// Controller
$obj = new Book;
$get = $obj->ranks()->orderBy('rating', 'desc')->get();
```

It throws this error:

> Call to a member function groupBy() on integer

Any idea how can I fix this problem?

Comment: You might find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267550/how-to-group-and-sum-a-pivot-table-column-in-eloquent-relationship

Answer (score 2):

```
public function ranks() {
    return $this->hasMany(Rank::class)
        ->select('book_id', \DB::raw('sum(`rating`) as `rank`'))
        ->groupBy('book_id');
}

$books = Book::with('ranks')->get();
$sortedBooks = $books->sortByDesc(function($book) {
    return $book->ranks->sum('rank');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this load all `Book` models into the memory and then sort them? That could lead to high memory usage. It would be preferable to sorting in the database layer.

Comment: Do you mean `Rank` models?

Comment: No, I mean the `Book` models. Say, there are 1000 books, and you only want the 10 best ranked. Then you would need to load 1000 `Book` + their `Ranks` in order to sort the 10 best.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what the question was about.