# How to add a sum of amount constraint in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a database with the following Relations:

There are `projects` - something people can purchase, also has `user_id`,

There are `backers` - the people that purchase,

There are `orders` - each order is a purchase of a `Project` by `Backer` (`Backer` can only purchase each `Project` once). THere is an amount - showing how much a `Backer` has paid to purchase the `Project`

[image]

What I need is to write the following query - given the `$user_id`, `$count` and `$sum` find all Backers that have invested at least in `$count` number of projects with `user_id` equal to `$user_id` and having the sum of their purchases for those projects higher then `$sum`.

```
  Backer::whereHas('projects', function ($q) use ($sum, $userId){

        $q->where('user_id', $userId);

    }, '>=', $leastProjectCount)->get();
```

but it does not constraint the `$sum` of purchases

**Update:**
So I came up with this query:

```
select  * from `backers` \r\n
                    WHERE id > 0 \r\n
                    AND (select count(*)\r\n
                           FROM `projects` \r\n
                           inner join `orders` on `projects`.`id` = `orders`.`project_id` \r\n
                           where `backers`.`id` = `orders`.`backer_id` \r\n
                           and `user_id` = 6 \r\n
                           and exists (\r\n
                               select * \r\n
                               from `tags` \r\n
                               inner join `project_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `project_tag`.`tag_id` \r\n
                               where `projects`.`id` = `project_tag`.`project_id` \r\n
                               and `id` in (27)\r\n
                           ) \r\n
                          ) >= 1 \r\n
                    AND (select sum(orders.amount)\r\n
                           FROM `projects` \r\n
                           inner join `orders` on `projects`.`id` = `orders`.`project_id` \r\n
                           where `backers`.`id` = `orders`.`backer_id` \r\n
                           and `user_id` = 6 \r\n
                           and exists (\r\n
                               select * \r\n
                               from `tags` \r\n
                               inner join `project_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `project_tag`.`tag_id` \r\n
                               where `projects`.`id` = `project_tag`.`project_id` \r\n
                               and `id` in (27)\r\n
                           ) \r\n
                          ) >= 12
```

note that the subqueries are almost the same, except that the first uses `COunt(*)` and the second uses `sum(orders.amount)`. And also note that this query runs if all the parameters were set, but it can be shorter, when some parameters are not set. The problem I am getting is that I don't have pagination with such a query.

Comment: Can we forget about all the laravel/eloquent stuff for now, and just focus on the raw sql?

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267550/how-to-group-and-sum-a-pivot-table-column-in-eloquent-relationship

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
Backer::whereHas('projects', function ($q) use ($sum, $userId){
    $q->where('user_id', $userId)
        ->havingRaw('SUM(amount) > ? ', [$sum]);

}, '>=', $leastProjectCount)->get();
```

Comment: This query does not group the orders of the project. It just checks if the sum of each project is more than some amount, not the aggregate of orders for that backer. I have tried this already.

Comment: You want the *total amount* of all the backer's orders (with `$userId`) to be higher than `$sum`, right? The query does that for me. Can you post some sample data where it doesn't work?

Comment: You can examine the query  - https://pastebin.com/JXA9xdqL, you see, it does  not have the grouping of the projects (orders) and that way, there is nothing to sum, it just takes the same amount.

Comment: It takes the amount of all the backer's orders and calculates their sum. Isn't that what you want? Did you try this exact query?

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?